# jQueryUI dialog selected image in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQueryUI dialog to open some content, but in IE it appears that a "border" is added around images. When I click within the dialog it deselects it (so not a border but just a selected border, not sure if that makes sense).

Is there a way for me to remove it? As an example, click on "Read More" on the first competition here ([Example](http://www.decorex.co.za/shows/competitions/joburg/)) to view the border around the "Barrier" logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
a:active, a:selected, a:visited { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```